# Cannot migrate Data from 1.6 to 2.0 "core_config_data" document does not exist in the destination resource

Tags: database, migration, magento2-migration-tool

I'm trying to migrate data from `1.6.0.0` to the latest version of magento but am getting the following error:

> Integrity check failed due to "core_config_data" document does not
>   exist in the destination resource.

The table exists in the magento 2.1.7 database as `mgnb_core_config_data`

Here is the `config.xml` info.

```
<source>
        <database host="localhost" name="old_db" user="user"  password="pass"/>
    </source>
    <destination>
        <database host="localhost" name="new_db" user="user"   password="pass"/>
    </destination>
    <options>
    <dest_prefix>mgnb_</dest_prefix>
    <crypt_key>adfabde1a4e1533ec61egggae16e58abb66</crypt_key>
```

last post was not very legible. 
**Config.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
* Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
-->
<config xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance&quot; xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../config.xsd">
<steps mode="settings">
<step title="Settings Step">
<integrity>Migration\Step\Settings\Integrity</integrity>
<data>Migration\Step\Settings\Data</data>
</step>
<step title="Stores Step">
<integrity>Migration\Step\Stores\Integrity</integrity>
<data>Migration\Step\Stores\Data</data>
<volume>Migration\Step\Stores\Volume</volume>
</step>
</steps>
<steps mode="data">
<step title="Data Integrity Step">
<integrity>Migration\Step\DataIntegrity\Integrity</integrity>
</step>
<step title="EAV Step">
<integrity>Migration\Step\Eav\Integrity</integrity>
<data>Migration\Step\Eav\Data</data>
<volume>Migration\Step\Eav\Volume</volume>
</step>
<step title="Customer Attributes Step">
<integrity>Migration\Step\Customer\Integrity</integrity>
<data>Migration\Step\Customer\Data</data>
<volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
</step>
<step title="Map Step">
<integrity>Migration\Step\Map\Integrity</integrity>
<data>Migration\Step\Map\Data</data>
<volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
</step>
<step title="Url Rewrite Step">
<integrity>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</integrity>
<data>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</data>
<volume>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</volume>
</step>
<step title="Log Step">
<integrity>Migration\Step\Log\Integrity</integrity>
<data>Migration\Step\Log\Data</data>
<volume>Migration\Step\Log\Volume</volume>
</step>
<step title="Ratings Step">
<integrity>Migration\Step\Ratings\Integrity</integrity>
<data>Migration\Step\Ratings\Data</data>
<volume>Migration\Step\Ratings\Volume</volume>
</step>
<step title="ConfigurablePrices step">
<integrity>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Integrity</integrity>
<data>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Data</data>
<volume>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Volume</volume>
</step>
<step title="OrderGrids Step">
<integrity>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Integrity</integrity>
<data>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Data</data>
<volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
</step>
<step title="Tier Price Step">
<integrity>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Integrity</integrity>
<data>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Data</data>
<volume>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Volume</volume>
</step>
<step title="SalesIncrement Step">
<integrity>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Integrity</integrity>
<data>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Data</data>
<volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
</step>
<step title="PostProcessing Step">
<data>Migration\Step\PostProcessing\Data</data>
</step>
</steps>
<steps mode="delta">
<step title="Customer Attributes Step">
<delta>Migration\Step\Customer\Delta</delta>
<volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
</step>
<step title="Map Step">
<delta>Migration\Step\Map\Delta</delta>
<volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
</step>
<step title="Log Step">
<delta>Migration\Step\Log\Delta</delta>
<volume>Migration\Step\Log\Volume</volume>
</step>
<step title="OrderGrids Step">
<delta>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Delta</delta>
<volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
</step>
<step title="SalesIncrement Step">
<delta>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Delta</delta>
<volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
</step>
</steps>
<source>
<database host="localhost" name="magold" user="kxxxxx" password="xxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
</source>
<destination>
<database host="localhost" name="magnew" user="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" password="xxxxxxxxx"/>
</destination>
<options>
<dest_prefix>mgnb_</dest_prefix>
<crypt_key>adfabde1a4e1533ec61eae16e58abb66</crypt_key>
<map_file>etc/ce-to-ce/1.6.0.0/map.xml.dist</map_file>
<eav_map_file>etc/ce-to-ce/map-eav.xml.dist</eav_map_file>
<eav_document_groups_file>etc/ce-to-ce/eav-document-groups.xml.dist</eav_document_groups_file>
<eav_attribute_groups_file>etc/ce-to-ce/eav-attribute-groups.xml.dist</eav_attribute_groups_file>
<log_map_file>etc/ce-to-ce/map-log.xml.dist</log_map_file>
<log_document_groups_file>etc/ce-to-ce/log-document-groups.xml.dist</log_document_groups_file>
<settings_map_file>etc/ce-to-ce/settings.xml.dist</settings_map_file>
<customer_map_file>etc/ce-to-ce/1.6.0.0/map-customer.xml.dist</customer_map_file>
<customer_document_groups_file>etc/ce-to-ce/customer-document-groups.xml.dist</customer_document_groups_file>
<customer_attribute_groups_file>etc/ce-to-ce/1.6.0.0/customer-attribute-groups.xml.dist</customer_attribute_groups_file>
<delta_document_groups_file>etc/ce-to-ce/1.6.0.0/deltalog.xml.dist</delta_document_groups_file>
<order_grids_document_groups_file>etc/ce-to-ce/order-grids-document-groups.xml.dist</order_grids_document_groups_file>
<map_document_groups>etc/ce-to-ce/map-document-groups.xml.dist</map_document_groups>
<class_map>etc/ce-to-ce/class-map.xml.dist</class_map>
<tier_price_map_file>etc/ce-to-ce/map-tier-price.xml.dist</tier_price_map_file>
<!--
In case bulk_size=0 it will be auto-detected for every document.
-->
<bulk_size>0</bulk_size>
<!--
Set direct_document_copy = 1 for better performance.
NOTE: 'source' and 'destination' databases MUST be placed on the same MySQL instance
and 'destination' user MUST be granted with 'SELECT' permissions on 'source' database
-->
<direct_document_copy>0</direct_document_copy>
<source_prefix />
<dest_prefix />
<auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>0</auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>
<log_file>migration.log</log_file>
<progress_bar_format>%percent%% [%bar%] Remaining Time: %remaining%</progress_bar_format>
<upgrade_customer_password_hash>1</upgrade_customer_password_hash>
<edition_migrate>ce-to-ce</edition_migrate>
<edition_number>1.6.0.0</edition_number>
<init_statements_source>SET NAMES utf8;</init_statements_source>
<init_statements_destination>SET NAMES utf8;</init_statements_destination>
<crypt_key />
</options>
</config>
```

Here you go, database details have been xxxx'ed out

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../config.xsd">
    <steps mode="settings">
        <step title="Settings Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Settings\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Settings\Data</data>
        </step>
        <step title="Stores Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Stores\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Stores\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Stores\Volume</volume>
        </step>
    </steps>
    <steps mode="data">
        <step title="Data Integrity Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\DataIntegrity\Integrity</integrity>
        </step>
        <step title="EAV Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Eav\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Eav\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Eav\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Customer\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Customer\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Map Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Map\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Map\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Url Rewrite Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Log Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Log\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Log\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Log\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Ratings Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Ratings\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Ratings\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Ratings\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="ConfigurablePrices step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="OrderGrids Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Tier Price Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="PostProcessing Step">
            <data>Migration\Step\PostProcessing\Data</data>
        </step>
    </steps>
    <steps mode="delta">
        <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Customer\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Map Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Map\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Log Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Log\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Log\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="OrderGrids Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
        </step>
    </steps>
    <source>
        <database host="localhost" name="magold" user="kxxxxx"  password="xxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
    </source>
    <destination>
        <database host="localhost" name="magnew" user="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"   password="xxxxxxxxx"/>
    </destination>
    <options>
    <dest_prefix>mgnb_</dest_prefix>
    <crypt_key>adfabde1a4e1533ec61eae16e58abb66</crypt_key>
        <map_file>etc/ce-to-ce/1.6.0.0/map.xml.dist</map_file>
        <eav_map_file>etc/ce-to-ce/map-eav.xml.dist</eav_map_file>
        <eav_document_groups_file>etc/ce-to-ce/eav-document-groups.xml.dist</eav_document_groups_file>
        <eav_attribute_groups_file>etc/ce-to-ce/eav-attribute-groups.xml.dist</eav_attribute_groups_file>
        <log_map_file>etc/ce-to-ce/map-log.xml.dist</log_map_file>
        <log_document_groups_file>etc/ce-to-ce/log-document-groups.xml.dist</log_document_groups_file>
        <settings_map_file>etc/ce-to-ce/settings.xml.dist</settings_map_file>
        <customer_map_file>etc/ce-to-ce/1.6.0.0/map-customer.xml.dist</customer_map_file>
        <customer_document_groups_file>etc/ce-to-ce/customer-document-groups.xml.dist</customer_document_groups_file>
        <customer_attribute_groups_file>etc/ce-to-ce/1.6.0.0/customer-attribute-groups.xml.dist</customer_attribute_groups_file>
        <delta_document_groups_file>etc/ce-to-ce/1.6.0.0/deltalog.xml.dist</delta_document_groups_file>
        <order_grids_document_groups_file>etc/ce-to-ce/order-grids-document-groups.xml.dist</order_grids_document_groups_file>
        <map_document_groups>etc/ce-to-ce/map-document-groups.xml.dist</map_document_groups>
        <class_map>etc/ce-to-ce/class-map.xml.dist</class_map>
        <tier_price_map_file>etc/ce-to-ce/map-tier-price.xml.dist</tier_price_map_file>
        <!--
        In case bulk_size=0 it will be auto-detected for every document.
        -->
        <bulk_size>0</bulk_size>
        <!--
        Set direct_document_copy = 1 for better performance.
        NOTE: 'source' and 'destination' databases MUST be placed on the same MySQL instance
        and 'destination' user MUST be granted with 'SELECT' permissions on 'source' database
         -->
        <direct_document_copy>0</direct_document_copy>
        <source_prefix />
        <dest_prefix />
        <auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>0</auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>
        <log_file>migration.log</log_file>
        <progress_bar_format>%percent%% [%bar%] Remaining Time: %remaining%</progress_bar_format>
        <upgrade_customer_password_hash>1</upgrade_customer_password_hash>
        <edition_migrate>ce-to-ce</edition_migrate>
        <edition_number>1.6.0.0</edition_number>
        <init_statements_source>SET NAMES utf8;</init_statements_source>
        <init_statements_destination>SET NAMES utf8;</init_statements_destination>
        <crypt_key />
    </options>
</config>
```

Any idea what is wrong

Comment: can you show your config.xml of your migration settings?

Comment: Please you can remove from ans, please post in questions. I added here

Answer (score 0):

here you go, database details have been xxxx'ed out

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../config.xsd">
    <steps mode="settings">
        <step title="Settings Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Settings\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Settings\Data</data>
        </step>
        <step title="Stores Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Stores\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Stores\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Stores\Volume</volume>
        </step>
    </steps>
    <steps mode="data">
        <step title="Data Integrity Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\DataIntegrity\Integrity</integrity>
        </step>
        <step title="EAV Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Eav\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Eav\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Eav\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Customer\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Customer\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Map Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Map\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Map\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Url Rewrite Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Log Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Log\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Log\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Log\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Ratings Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Ratings\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Ratings\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Ratings\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="ConfigurablePrices step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="OrderGrids Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Tier Price Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="PostProcessing Step">
            <data>Migration\Step\PostProcessing\Data</data>
        </step>
    </steps>
    <steps mode="delta">
        <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Customer\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Map Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Map\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Log Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Log\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Log\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="OrderGrids Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
        </step>
    </steps>
    <source>
        <database host="localhost" name="magold" user="kxxxxx" password="xxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
    </source>
    <destination>
        <database host="localhost" name="magnew" user="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" password="xxxxxxxxx"/>
    </destination>
    <options>
        <dest_prefix>mgnb_</dest_prefix>
        <crypt_key>adfabde1a4e1533ec61eae16e58abb66</crypt_key>
        <map_file>etc/ce-to-ce/1.6.0.0/map.xml.dist</map_file>
        <eav_map_file>etc/ce-to-ce/map-eav.xml.dist</eav_map_file>
        <eav_document_groups_file>etc/ce-to-ce/eav-document-groups.xml.dist</eav_document_groups_file>
        <eav_attribute_groups_file>etc/ce-to-ce/eav-attribute-groups.xml.dist</eav_attribute_groups_file>
        <log_map_file>etc/ce-to-ce/map-log.xml.dist</log_map_file>
        <log_document_groups_file>etc/ce-to-ce/log-document-groups.xml.dist</log_document_groups_file>
        <settings_map_file>etc/ce-to-ce/settings.xml.dist</settings_map_file>
        <customer_map_file>etc/ce-to-ce/1.6.0.0/map-customer.xml.dist</customer_map_file>
        <customer_document_groups_file>etc/ce-to-ce/customer-document-groups.xml.dist</customer_document_groups_file>
        <customer_attribute_groups_file>etc/ce-to-ce/1.6.0.0/customer-attribute-groups.xml.dist</customer_attribute_groups_file>
        <delta_document_groups_file>etc/ce-to-ce/1.6.0.0/deltalog.xml.dist</delta_document_groups_file>
        <order_grids_document_groups_file>etc/ce-to-ce/order-grids-document-groups.xml.dist</order_grids_document_groups_file>
        <map_document_groups>etc/ce-to-ce/map-document-groups.xml.dist</map_document_groups>
        <class_map>etc/ce-to-ce/class-map.xml.dist</class_map>
        <tier_price_map_file>etc/ce-to-ce/map-tier-price.xml.dist</tier_price_map_file>
        <!--
        In case bulk_size=0 it will be auto-detected for every document.
        -->
        <bulk_size>0</bulk_size>
        <!--
        Set direct_document_copy = 1 for better performance.
        NOTE: 'source' and 'destination' databases MUST be placed on the same MySQL instance
        and 'destination' user MUST be granted with 'SELECT' permissions on 'source' database
         -->
        <direct_document_copy>0</direct_document_copy>
        <source_prefix/>
        <dest_prefix/>
        <auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>0</auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>
        <log_file>migration.log</log_file>
        <progress_bar_format>%percent%% [%bar%] Remaining Time: %remaining%</progress_bar_format>
        <upgrade_customer_password_hash>1</upgrade_customer_password_hash>
        <edition_migrate>ce-to-ce</edition_migrate>
        <edition_number>1.6.0.0</edition_number>
        <init_statements_source>SET NAMES utf8;</init_statements_source>
        <init_statements_destination>SET NAMES utf8;</init_statements_destination>
        <crypt_key/>
    </options>
</config>
```